# How to search for emails with same subject?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search Outlook by email received date and time, for specific subject email and then save its attachment in designated folder.

It gets stuck where I search for email with specific subject.

```
Set foundEmails = searchFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'KSA RDC - ECOM Inventory Report'")
```

```vb
Sub SearchAndDownloadAttachments()
    ' Declare variables for the Outlook application and folder
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim inboxFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim searchFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim foundEmails As Search
    Dim email As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim attach As Outlook.Attachment
    ' Set the Outlook application and namespace
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Set the inbox folder and search folder
    Set inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set searchFolder = inboxFolder.Folders("IT Reports")

    ' Search for emails with the specified subject
    Set foundEmails = searchFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'KSA RDC - ECOM Inventory Report'")

    ' Loop through the found emails
    For Each email In foundEmails
        ' Declare variables for the email name and received time
        Dim emailName As String
        Dim receivedTime As Date
        Dim attachmentName As String
        ' Set the email name and received time
        emailName = email.SenderName
        receivedTime = email.receivedTime

        ' Loop through the attachments of the email
        For Each attach In email.Attachments
            attachmentName = attach.Filename
            ' Copy the attachment to the specified folder
            attach.SaveAsFile "C:\Attachments\" & attachmentName & "-" & emailName & " - " & Format(receivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
        Next
    Next email
End Sub
```

Comment: Try diferently declaring `foundEmails`: `Dim foundEmails As Items`. `Items.Restrict` should return a items collection... And you may also face an error when try saving the attachment, I think.

Comment: The error is type: Mismatch

Comment: This should be even more eloquent, I think... Did you try changing the declaration as I suggested above? If not, what does it cost you to do it?

Comment: yeah, I tried to change Dim foundEmails As Search to Dim foundEmails As Items. Items.Restrict but getting type mismatch error again and then my sub is highlighetd with yellow and dim is highlighetd with blue

Comment: Also I kept it to :Dim foundEmails As Items" but then line is giving "object required" error

Comment: You should declare it `Dim foundEmails As Items`... It was a second sentence after.

Comment: yes, I did the same and then in search I changed it to search

Dim foundEmails As Items

Set foundEmails = Items.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'KSA RDC - ECOM Inventory Report'")

Erorr: Object required

Comment: Is there a sub folder named "IT Reports" in `InBox'? When stopped on error, moving the cursor over `searchFolder`, what does it show?

Comment: Keep `Set foundEmails = searchFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'KSA RDC - ECOM Inventory Report'")` as it was! I only tried emphasizing what `Items.Restric` does return...

Comment: Yes, it is "IT Reports" and search folder is showing same name when i am hoovering the cursor over it, but found email is showing "Nothing". Should I try to change the name of Folder to Inbox?

Comment: This only means that there is  **no mail with the subject "KSA RDC - ECOM Inventory Report" exists in that subfolder**.  The used string must look **exactly as the subject looks**...

Comment: I just check now, and i run the code as you suggested before and ran. But emails were saved as PNG and getting a msg

microsoft excel is waiting for 'Report: KSA RDC - Ecom Inventory report - Message(HTML)' to complete an OLE action

Comment: In my comment I was trying to suggest that the attachment will not be saved as it should, it will not have any extension. I can show you how it's better, but i cannot understand what you mean when saying "*emails were saved as PNG and getting a msg microsoft excel is waiting for 'Report: KSA RDC - Ecom Inventory report - Message(HTML)' to complete an OLE action*". Is this error raised on the above code line `attach.SaveAsFile ...` or when you try opening the saved file?

Comment: Please, try the code answer I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next adapted code. Take care to **change the subject string, to be exactly as the one you try returning**:

```
Sub SearchAndDownloadAttachments()
    ' Declare variables for the Outlook application and folder
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application, outlookNamespace As NameSpace
    Dim inboxFolder As MAPIFolder, searchFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim foundEmails As Items, email As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim attach As Outlook.Attachment
    
    ' Set the Outlook application and namespace
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Set the inbox folder and search folder
    Set inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set searchFolder = inboxFolder.Folders("IT Reports")

    ' Search for emails with the specified subject
    Set foundEmails = searchFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'KSA RDC - ECOM Inventory Report'") 'change here the exact spelled subject string!

    ' Loop through the found emails
    For Each email In foundEmails
        ' Declare variables for the email name and received time
        Dim emailName As String, receivedTime As Date, attachmentName As String
        Dim ext As String, nameRoot As String 'new declarations
        
        ' Set the email name and received time
        emailName = email.SenderName
        receivedTime = email.receivedTime

        ' Loop through the attachments of the email
        For Each attach In email.Attachments
            attachmentName = attach.FileName
            ext = Right(attachmentName, Len(attachmentName) - InStrRev(attachmentName, ".") + 1) 'extract extension
            nameRoot = left(attachmentName, Len(attachmentName) - Len(ext)) 'the remained name (without extension)
            
            ' Copy the attachment to the specified folder
            attach.SaveAsFile "C:\Attachments\" & nameRoot & "-" & emailName & " - " & _
                                        Format(receivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ext
        Next
    Next email
End Sub
```

Your last error may be related to the fact that `Outlook` is not able to save a file **without extension** and Excel remains hanged on this `Outlook` attempt...

Please, send some feedback after testing the code.

Comment: Invanlid next contril varianble reference. at Next email

Comment: @Shariq Shariq Please, test the updated code. It was not tested, and it was missing a `Next` code line...